# update_attributes() does not works properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

```
@related=Book.find_all_by_related(@book.related)
if @related.count>1
  @related.each do |b|
    b.update_attributes(params[:book])
  end
end
```

I'm using rails 2.3.5. for above code, first iteration works fine and show true. but for next iteration, b.update_attributes() shows false . All parameters are reaching in the iterations. Method update_attributes() have any conditions?

Comment: what d params[:book] holds ?

Comment: Maybe some validations fail? Check your records for validity.

Comment: I think params[:book] gives you data only for 1(current) book

Comment: parameters (from editing form)

Comment: I've checked if params[:book] passing to second iteration. and seems passing

Comment: If it' fails then just after the update_attributes, try to debug. "raise b.errors.inspect" .
Write above raise statement just after the update_attributes line.  That will show if any validation is failing.

Comment: If it works in the first iteration and fails in the following iterations, then probably there  is a uniqueness validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model specified attr_accessible attributes, only those attributes will be updated.

Use attr_accessible to prevent mass assignment (by users) of attributes that should not be editable by a user. Mass assignment is used in create and update methods of your standard controller.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :login, :password
end
```

So, doing the following will merrily return true, but will not update the status attribute.

```
@user.update_attributes(:status => 'active')
```

If you want to update the status attribute, you should assign it separately.

```
@user.status = 'active'
save
```